# Rails resources have new params; Update form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I changed my `config/routes.rb` so that a resource uses a different parameter

```
resources :users, param: :username
```

That way instead of `users/:id`, `users/:id/edit`, etc.
I now use `users/:username`, `users/:username/edit`, etc.

Then in my UserController I populate `@user` like so

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
```

And for the most part everything works nicely, and I have more meaningful urls.

The problem is I have a really complex form partial that I don't want to split up into two different forms (I still want to use the partial)

but now this:

```
form_for @user do |f|
   ....
```

It routes to its respective update actions but it replaces :username with the id of the @user, effectively causing me to find no user using `@user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])` for the update action.  I could include `form_for @user, params: {username: @user.username} do |f|` but this won't work unless @user is populated.

How can I get my form_for to route to my update and create actions respectively, while maintaining my url of `/users/:username` from my resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use url_helpers to assist you in creating the url that will route to your respective actions

```
form_for @user, url: {action: (@user.new_record? ? "create" : "update") } do |f|
```

Thus, it will be

`url: {action: "create"}` if `@user` is a new record

or

`url: {action: "update"}` if `@user` is not a new record

Rails will take care of the rest.